# Run jQuery function via php on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am using a form to allow file download and to store the number of downloads but now I can't seem to find a way to `fadeIn` a subscribe div *(#cover)* on form success..

This is my form:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="free-download" id="free-download">
    <button class="download" type="submit" name="clicks" onclick="window.open('download/imagins_._ro_free_files_format_icons.rar')">download (<span class="small"><?php echo getClickCount(); ?> times</span>)</button>
</form>
```

Is there a jquery way of doing this?

This is what I tried:

```
$("#free-download").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
          $('#cover').fadeIn(600);
          $('body').addClass('hidescroll');
});
```

### Update

By changing the form action to `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`
and adding the following (below) I managed to add an echo to the page
on form success, but how do I have the #cover div fadeIn?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['clicks'])) 
{ 
    echo "<p class='section-desc'>You just downloaded it</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing the `echo` in the `action` attribute of your `<form>` tag but this is not the problem here. Just pointing out.

Comment: @D4V1D, adding `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` isn't changing anything, is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: @D4V1D I found a way to do this, I answered my own question, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working solution

Use php to echo a script tag containing whatever you want to achieve
on submit success (in my case, a div fadeIn).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['clicks'])) 
{ 
    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $( "#cover").fadeIn();
    });
    </script>';
}
?>
```